# Is it possible to implement a real FIFO mutex (in c)?

Tags: multithreading

Is it possible to implement a real FIFO mutex meaning that it is guaranteed that a requesting thread is granted its request only if all "younger" threads have been granted their request. Note that the order in granting the requests of two threads that requested at the same time is not relevant meaning that the solution can .

If the answer is no, is it possible to guarantee the following condition:
Let x_t be the time in which thread x has requested.

x is younger by n than y if and only if y_t - x_t = n.
x is at least younger by n than y if and only if y_t - x_t >= n.

The condition is that there exists n so that a thread is granted its request only if all threads at least younger than it by n have been granted their request.

Note: my terminology may not be accurate. With "requesting" I mean requesting acquiring and locking the mutex. With "granting" I mean locking the mutex by the specified thread.

Comment: FYI, what you are asking about has a name, it's called a [_fair_ mutex](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/70125/43896), and the problem that it solves is called [_thread starvation_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starvation_(computer_science)). Fairness practically never is the default, and in many systems, it's not even an option. Fairness comes with a cost, and it has no benefit unless the mutex is heavily contested. But if the mutex is heavily contested, you can reap much _more_ benefit by re-architecting the application to remove the contention.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it is *impossible*?

Answer (score 1):

Q: What does "in C" mean? You can do anything in C if you're willing to write the code.*

Are you asking whether a fair mutex can be provided by an operating system? That's almost trivially easy. The OS already must have a container for each mutex in which it stores the IDs of all of the threads that are waiting for the mutex. All you have to do to ensure fairness is to change the scheduling strategy to always wake the thread whose ID has been in the container longer than any other when the mutex is released.

Are you asking whether you can implement a fair mutex in application code, by using one or more OS-provided unfair mutexes? That is possible, but it won't be as clean as an OS-provided fair mutex. One approach would be to have a pool of [*condition variables*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)#Condition_variables) (CVs), and have each different thread use a different CV to await its turn to enter the mutex. When a thread tries and fails to acquire the mutex, it would grab a CV from the pool, put a pointer to the CV into a FIFO queue, and then it would wait on the CV.

Whenever a thread releases the mutex, it would signal the CV that's been waiting longest in the queue. The thread that was awakened, would then return its CV to the pool, and enter the mutex.

---

* But see [Greenspun's Tenth Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greenspun%27s_tenth_rule).